# Why does Emacs turn TAB (\t) into multiple spaces when backspacing?

Tags: emacs, whitespace, backspace

Something I've encountered, notaby within CC-Mode related languages, is that when I press TAB and then backspace, Emacs then treats it as if it were 4 spaces (or however big my tabstop was). Why does Emacs have this behavior and is there a way to override it in the Major CC-Mode and perhaps other major modes that have a similar behavior?

I have tried playing around with the Emacs indent, offset, and hooks in my `init.el` though haven't gotten any notabe results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See:

- <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(ccmode)Hungry WS Deletion`
- <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> `c-backspace-function`

Comment: To clarify what I did, I did `(setq backward-delete-char-untabify-method nil)` to basically make Emacs delete one character and not turn a TAB into spaces